# Integrating 2nf and 3nf databases

Tags: database, integration, servicebus, 3nf

I have a legacy IT environment with multiple systems, each of which has it's own database which references the same data about our customers.  I.e. a sales system, an accounting system, and an operations system, all of which have data about the same customers, accounts, and products.

In some cases this data is stored in 2nf, and some cases in 3nf.  Are there best practices or known algorithms for integrating the two?

E.g. is there a way to make a change to a customer in the 3nf sales system and then reliably update the same information about the customer in the 2nf operations system?

Thanks,

Ean

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to make a change to a customer in the 3nf sales system and then reliably update the same information about the customer in the 2nf operations system?

Not without a lot of hard work.

In the general case, the only way to make that work is to store the matching keys in tables, and use those matching keys to propagate changes. And there are still a lot of things that might prevent that from working.

- Incompatible column widths.
- Incompatible permissions.
- Incompatible constraints.
- Missing data.
- Duplicate data.

Matching keys can involve a lot of hands-on work. For example, say "customers" has  five rows where the customer's name is "David Small", and the operations system has three rows.  How many "David Small"s are there? How do they match up? You can't tell by the name alone. You have to dig through other data--addresses, purchase history, etc. There's no way to tell ahead of time how *much* of that data you'll have to wade through, and when you're finished you *still* might not be able to tell which matches which. Automating it is hard.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Presuming, for a moment, that data has been cleansed and is duplicated accurately in all systems, how would the method of storing matching keys work?

Are you suggesting that I could add a key column to a 2nf table wherever a 3nf table would have a fk?  

So, if the 2nf customer system had a table "customer" like this:

**fname, lname, address, company**

I would add a new field companyid to customer, so it would look like this:

**fname, lname, address, company, companyid**

right?

thanks,

Ean

Comment: No, you shouldn't change the existing tables. Instead, you create a new table that contains the primary key columns from the 2NF table and the primary key columns of the 3NF table. You'll need to look hard at the tables that have transitive dependencies--using a key mapping table might not be sufficient to guarantee consistent updates.